# how to make sure not to read another page only after loging in

Tags: php

here you may find my verification code 
with this code i want not to redirect to another page only after logging in
how shall i do ?

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
    session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] != 'ok') {
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't check the content of session before ssession has been started. As for "how it is done in professional projects": the access restriction is often define in the routing configuration, which the is used to check, if user has been authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

i would use `isset` combined with `empty` just for extra precaution

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login'])) {
   header("location:user.php");
}
else {
  header("location:login_form.php");
}
```

don't use exit(); just redirect